# On the separability of Gaussian and Laplacian Operator

Tags: normal-distribution

From what I understand, one advantage of Gaussian function for image smoothing is that it's separable. We can have $2n$ operations instead of $n^2$ (multiply $n\times n$ mask with an image $m\times m$, where $m$ not necessarily equals $n$):
$$
G_{\sigma}\left( x,y \right) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma ^2}}e^{\frac{-\left( x^2+y^2 \right)}{2\sigma ^2}}
$$

[image]

Let $h(x,y)$ be the output image after Gaussian filter $g(x,y)$ on input image $I(x,y)$, then

$$
\begin{align}
h(x,y) = I(x,y) \times g(x,y) \cdots (\text{$n^2$ ops})\tag{1}\label{tag1}\\
h(x,y) = \left( I(x,y)\times g_1(x) \right) \times g_2(y)\cdots (\text{$2n$ ops}) \tag{2}\label{tag2}\\
\end{align}
$$

I am not sure how that separability reduced number of operations from $n^2$ to just $2n$ please?

Comment: This is also a good fit for [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) as would probably be most questions about number of computer operations, as well as of course for [Signal Processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)